# Is casting possible in loop in c?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Having this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    void *mem = malloc(10);
    for(int i =0; i<10 ; i++)
        (char*)mem[i] = 'a'; //want to cast in loop
}
```

gives error

```
warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   (char*)mem[i] = 'a';
warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
error: invalid use of void expression
   (char*)mem[i] = 'a';
```

However, having to done cast *before* loop is ok:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *mem = malloc(10);
    for(int i =0; i<10 ; i++)
        mem[i] = 'a';
}
```

No cast is done by loop's steps. So why cannot I do the former, where I cast pointer in each loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(char*)mem[i]` casts the result of the index operation, which is already a semantic error since you can't index into `void *`. This code fixes your issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    void *mem = malloc(10);
    for(int i =0; i<10 ; i++)
        ((char*)mem)[i] = 'a'; //want to cast in loop
}
```

Comment: so `[]` has precedence before cast?

Comment: Precisely, yes.